# Promises not working properly with nested query.each and parse.save

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

The following code is for a background job on parse and for some reason the code is not working as expected in sequence order and it seems that it is running ASYNC and promises are not working properly. i appreciate your help if any modification required to get the code working in a sequential manner.

NEW VERSION OF THE CODE:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("NewJob", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.run('Count1', {params}).then(function(recCount1)
{
    Query1.equalTo(<cond>);
    return Query1.each(

    function(Record1)
    {

        Record1.save().then(function(saverecord1)
        {
            Parse.Cloud.run('Count2', {params}).then(function(recCount2)
            {
                Query2.equalTo(<cond>);
                Query2.each(

                function(Record2)
                {
                    Record2.save().then(function(saverecord2)
                    {

                        Parse.Cloud.run('Count3', {params}).then(function(recCount3)
                        {
                            Query3.equalTo(<cond>);
                            Query3.each(

                            function(Record3)
                            {
                                Record3.save().then(function(saverecord3)
                                {
                                    //save success;
                                },
                                function(error)
                                {
                                    response.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
                                }).then(function(complete)
                                {
                                    response.success();
                                })
                            },{useMasterKey: true})
                        },
                        function(error)
                        {
                            response.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
                        })
                    },
                    function(error)
                    {
                        response.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
                    })
                },{useMasterKey: true})
            },
            function(error)
            {
                response.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
            })
        },
        function(error)
        {
            response.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
        })
    },{useMasterKey: true})
},
function(error)
{
    response.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
})
```

});

Comment: Can you add more details about the problem you're seeing other than "not working properly"?

Comment: @hooda the first query.each is working properly and the save inside it works but the inner query.each only work once although the query will return a lot and of course next level down for third query.each that is being executed once randomly. Even the execution seems to be randomly. As it start with first .each loop then in between second query.each and then back again to first query.i completely could not figure out the root cause here but I expect promises what do you think ?

Comment: Are you sure there are no error's being thrown? You have a failure handler on the top level promise, but not any of the child promises. Also you aren't returning the result of any of the child promises so errors will not bubble to the top.

Comment: No errors are thrown away and when I read the promises guide it says that no need to add errors on the child as it propagate to top level and that is one of the features for promises. What do you mean by not returning results of child promises , all callbacks for the .each are returning.

Comment: Here is a fiddle I made to demonstrate what I mean.  https://jsfiddle.net/gv6dL8xt/

Comment: Hello Hood, I will try that and let you know how it goes

Comment: Hello hood, I edit the corde as per above new version. The behavior a bit changed to better but not to the desired and expected output. Query 1 is parent records and query2 retrieve the childs for a record returned in Query1, Query3 is returning Childs for a record returned in Query2. So what happened in the new code changes is that all updates happens for all records in returned by Query1, and only last records and its details childs in query3 are updated. Can you please let me know what is going wrong in my code.